# Itemize Issues in a Table

Tags: tables

Nice people here have been able to help me get through this but am faced with a second issue with itemize in another column and it is being a challenge. Any help is very welcome. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,caption,enumitem,ragged2e}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}

\captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}

\caption{Selected Ebola Epidemic Compartmental Models, Analyses and Problem Formulations with References}

\small

\centering

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}

\begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{lll>{\RaggedRight}Xlc}

  \rowcolor{cyan}

  \specialrule{.2em}{.1em}{.1em}

  \textbf{Compartmental} & \textbf{Analysis} & \textbf{Problem} & \centering

  \textbf{Objective} & \textbf{Control} & \textbf{Reference}  \\

  \rowcolor{cyan}

  \textbf{Model} & & \textbf{Formulation} & & \textbf{Intervention} & \\

  \specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}

  SEIT & Sensitivity & Differential &

  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\RaggedRight

    \begin{itemize}[nosep]

      \item Evaluate various intervention strategies

      \item Determine model parameters by least square method

    \end{itemize}

  \end{minipage} &

  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\RaggedRight

    \begin{itemize}[nosep]

        \item Vaccination 

        \item isolation 

    \end{itemize}

  \end{minipage} & You and Me [1] \\

\end{tabularx}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you like to obtain something like this?
[image]

Actually essential change to your MWE is added column type `X` instead `l` for second list ... The code is (slightly rearranged):

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

    \usepackage{enumitem,ragged2e}
    \usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \centering
    \small
\caption{Selected Ebola Epidemic Compartmental Models, Analyses and Problem Formulations with References}
\begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{lllXXc}
    \rowcolor{cyan}
    \specialrule{.2em}{.1em}{.1em}
\textbf{Compartmental}  & \textbf{Analysis}         & \textbf{Problem} 
                        & \hfil\textbf{Objective}   & \hfil\textbf{Control}  
                        & \textbf{Reference}        \\
  \rowcolor{cyan}
\textbf{Model}          &                           & \textbf{Formulation}
                        &                           & \textbf{Intervention}
                        &                           \\
    \specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
SEIT & Sensitivity & Differential &
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
        \item Evaluate various intervention strategies
        \item Determine model parameters by least square method
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage} 
        &
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
        \item Vaccination
        \item isolation
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage} & You and Me [1] \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Zarko for your support and help. Have a good day. Works fine